# Maven Wrapper Lifecycle failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I am getting below error when I try to do a maven build using terminal from Intellij.

Just not sure what is to be done or what is the issue. The same configuration worked for earlier springboot projects.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
D:\springboot\api\streetapiservice>mvnw clean install
The system cannot find the path specified.
'B' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The directory name is invalid.
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:1 char:282
+ ... pe]::Tls12; $webclient.DownloadFile('https://repo.maven.apache.org/ma ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
 
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
```

**POM File**
Below is the pom file -- I have removed some dependencies. This was created using spring starter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>streetapiservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>streetapiservice</name>
    <description>Api for handling calls street api</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.7.0.1746</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
        <mock-sever-netty-version>3.10.8</mock-sever-netty-version>
        <apache-http-version>4.4.1</apache-http-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you try `mvnw clean install -e`

Comment: can you share us the pom file and the complete exception stack trace... it is inconclusive here. Add as many details as possible and also include the things that you tried.

Comment: @AbhishekDhoundiyal even with -e it returns the same error message

Comment: @Jayanth below is the pom file....  I have removed the spring based dependencies..

Comment: >using terminal from Intellij< Out of interest, does that mean that there is a terminal *in* IntelliJ? (I don't use IntelliJ)

Comment: @g00se -- yes.. you can have a local terminal in intellij

Comment: I'd be sorely tempted to see what happens when you make a copy of your project and run what is definitely the *real* Maven from a *real* terminal (cmd.exe) on it

Comment: @g00se - just because you said `sorely tempted`, I tried creating a new project from scratch and ran it via intellij terminal  and it ran...  :) looks like there is something wrong with my local configuration.... I have a way now.. thank you so much !! :)

Comment: Ha - that's IDEs for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- when i tried to run the same code via git bash, it ran fine.
- issue looks to be with the IDE
- reimporting the project fixed the issue